# AngularJS filter is requiring two clicks before it filters results

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner at angular. I am pretty certain I am doing this the completely incorrect way but because I finally have it "somewhat working" as it works on the second click I am stuck going in this direction and can't seem to figure out another way to do it.

The filter sorts on the second click because it is initialing as "undefined" before the first click and sets it based on that I believe.

In my html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 location-list" ng-repeat="key in careerlist.location">
                        <div class="locations" ng-click="careerlist.criteriaMatch()">{{key}}
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 job-container" ng-repeat="job in careerlist.career | filter : searchText | filter: selectExperience | filter: careerlist.criteria.name">
            <h2>
                {{job.title}}
            </h2>
            <h3>
                {{job.location}}
            </h3>
            <div class="job-description" ng-bind-html="job.description | limitHtml : 200">
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <button><a href="{{job.url}}">Read More</a></button>
        </div>
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller:

```
cl.criteriaMatch = function( criteria ) {
            jQuery(document).on('click', '.locations', function(){
                cl.criteria = {};
                console.log("just the element text " + jQuery(this).text());
                cl.criteria.name = jQuery(this).text();
                return function( criteria ) {
                    return criteria.name === criteria.name;
                };
            });

        };
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using jQuery to handle your click events and not Angular?

Comment: If you had something that we could use to reproduce this we could probably solve it a bit faster.  The code sample you have is incomplete to run in an environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-click` instead of `jQuery#on('click')`. Angular does not know that the filter should be updated.

**Update**

@Makoto points out that the click is bound twice. It very much looks like you should just remove the jQuery binding altogether. I would even go so far as suggesting removing jQuery from you project.

Comment: They're using both `ngClick` and `jquery.on('click')` to handle this.  The issue isn't how the click happens; I believe it to be that the click event happens *twice*; once with Angular knowing about it, and once with only jQuery knowing about it.

Comment: This was the partially the correct answer. The other issue was that I needed to add $event and $event.currentTarget instead of criteria. I did not give you enough code to allow you to test it so I understand that you could not have solved it completely for me but your answer led me in the right direction.